# Google SDK EMail Signature with HTML

Tags: google-admin-sdk

According to Google's Official Documentation on the Email Settings Signature API

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#updating_a_signature

I was trying to set the signature value to be html but was getting an error saying that I can't include < (which is from the ). 
Any work around?

The error message is 
The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character. 0

Comment: Are you doing that on your local machine or in a production environment with specific domain name?

Comment: i'm going in on a local dev machine.

Comment: The error message I'm getting is